# How to deny '/' path on Windows IIS

Tags: windows, iis

I have a couple ASP.NET core rest api's running under IIS.
They don't have a default index.html file.

I'm getting a lot of log spam from web crawlers and other bots that hit mysite.com/ (looking for the default index html).

I'd like for IIS to block these requests, preferably making it look like there is no HTTP server at all, whilst still allowing normal operation of my rest api (/api/....)

Is this possible or what is recommended for rest api projects that do not have a default page?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, you can block requests through url rewrite in iis, It can block requests according to url path, more           information you can refer to this link: [Request Blocking - rule template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template).

Comment: @samwu i want to block requests to any other path than /api/ would be a better way to put it. Even the home page (www.example.com/) should be blocked.

Comment: Then you can try to create a rule that only allows /api/, and then blocks other requests, but this seems difficult.